# Content translation in a sharepoint list form

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a sharepoint list form and now i need to translate the form lables and its contents (that are pulled from sharepoint list) to other languages dynamically.
I cannot use SharePoint language packs here and i need some API which can be used for free of cost to translate the content dynamically.

Thanks in advance,
Usha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register in some translation apps that provide translation API，like [Google translate api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=na-US-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1009135&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_297670895002-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7C%20US%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20EXA%20%7E%20ML%2FAI%20%7E%20Translation%20API%20%7E%20google%20translate%20api-KWID_43700037004364747-kwd-14329410560&utm_term=KW_google%20translate%20api-ST_google%20translate%20api&gclid=Cj0KCQjwufn8BRCwARIsAKzP69566nEFL8-x3e0SnS6vSGqP_qMinvoCziJxSpydm1KiNKceOPKIQGEaAvKbEALw_wcB)...
They will provide some free opportunities to use api, but the extra part needs to be paid.

Please refer to their documents for specific charging prices and methods and you can also find examples in their documentation.

My test code with baidu translate api for your reference:

```
<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./md5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var appid = 'appid';
var key = 'key';
var salt = (new Date).getTime();
var query = 'apple';
var from = 'en';
var to = 'zh';
var str1 = appid + query + salt +key;
var sign = MD5(str1);
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.fanyi.baidu.com/api/trans/vip/translate',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        q: query,
        appid: appid,
        salt: salt,
        from: from,
        to: to,
        sign: sign
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    } 
});

</script>
```

Test Result:

[image]